# Matlab :Unable to plot the continuous function

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot the relation between Concentration and Time.

The relation between concentration and time is expressed as a piecewise function

```
  C(t) =0 for                           t>=0  & t <=td
  C(t) =A_max(t-td)                     t>=td && t<=t_max
         3   
  C(t) = Σ   a(n)*e^-(b(n)*(t-t_max))   t> t_max  /exponential decay 
         n=1
```

The values td and t_max are input values

for  this piecewise function i have  written the following function which intakes the values of  td,t_max and  coefficients like a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b2  and plots Concentration Vs time

```
function c_o = Sample_function(td,t_max,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3)
t =(1:5:5000); % time of the sample post injection in mins
c_o =(0 : 2275.3 :113765); % activity of the sample calibrated with Average well counter    
A_max= max(c_o);%Max value of Concentration (Peak of the curve)

for i=1:length(t)

 if((t(i)>0) && (t(i)<=td))
    c_o(i)=0;

 elseif((t(i)>=td) && (t(i)<=t_max))
    c_o(i)= A_max*(t(i)-td);

 else(t(i)>t_max)
    c_o(i)=(a1*exp(-b1*(t(i)-t_max)))+(a2*exp(-b2*(t(i)- t_max)))+(a3*exp(-b3*(t(i)-t_max)));




 end


end


fprintf('plotting Data ...\n');
 %figure ;
 plot(c_o(i));
xlabel('time of the sample in minutes ');
ylabel('Activity of the sample Ba/ml');
title (' Input function: Activity sample VS time ');
pause;
end
```

The above function must plot the concentration values for each values of t,td.t_max, a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 are user given and the plot must vary accordingly as per values of t,td.t_max, a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3.

Kindly please review my code and if this is appropriate way to plot the piece wise function

Comment: Any error message? It's impossible to run your code without input data.

Comment: There is no error function,the function which i have written is peace wise function , and the Input values for td,t_max,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 can be varied..For example i have used values like Sample_function(10,40,1155,2000,2100,5,4,2) but i couldn't plot with these input values

Comment: Check the input of `plot`, its `0` and a scalar `0` is plotted. `'erasemode','background'` seems to be invalid usage of the function?

Comment: Exactly, the plot is 0 but i like continuous plot which is a function of t, it seems the loop is not even passing through function.. could you please let me know what's wrong in my for loop

Comment: I have edited my question and now its more descriptive , could anyone please review my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Matlab at hand now, so my answer may not work.
Try this:
erase the line:

```
plot(c_o(t(i)),'erasemode','background');
```

and put the following line after the `end` of the `for`:

plot(c_o);

There is one more thing that seems off.  You define t = [1 501 1001 1501 ... 4501]
And then inside the for you alter the c_o values as c_o(t(i)). This means that you only modify the 1st, 501th, 1001st ... values of c_o. Is this intended?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did not realize that mistake,I would like to modify every point in time, not 501st or 1001st , how should  modify my code so that data for every instant of time is plotted not at an interval of 500..

Comment: I am able to obtain the plot but unfortunately  i couldn't properly visualize the exponential decay value in my code,kindly let me know if you have any idea to overcome my problem

Comment: The code now shows that t has 10 values but c_o has more. So if you intend to plot c_o vs t there is an error you should try to correct. On the other hand, try to change the `c_o(t(i))` to `c_o(i)` and see if this helps. Keep in mind that in this case you are only altering the first 10 values of c_o.

Comment: Just one more comment: if you intend to plot c_o vs time (t?), then you need them to have the same length.  Then use `plot(t,c_o)`.